# iOS - UIPopOverController - Dynamic Menu?

Tags: ios, menu, uipopovercontroller, drop-down-menu

I know UIPopOverController can give a standard drop down but I'm curious if it can do a dynamic drop down.

The Dynamic drop down would take it one step further and clicking on any item in the list could expand out more options or preform some other action, similar to how file menus behave.

If any examples exist that would be appreciated.

Comment: you can put any view controller in a popover controller, including a navigation view, anything you've managed in a table view can be done there - - - cascading menus, with the while hierarchy remaining on screen would not be easy, and are a bad design UX anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no compelling reason why not, but you'd just have to write it all yourself (in a table view or otherwise). Popover controllers are just containers for view controllers: write a view controller that does what you want, and you're set.